# Use SQL Function as select parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table with a structure like this:

[image]

Each column is a hour of day (I can't change the structure of table)

If I want to get the value of 13:00pm I have to write a query like this:

```
SELECT
   TAB.[13]
FROM
  TABLE AS TAB
```

I want to know if is possible make something like this:

```
SELECT
   TAB.[TRY_CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(HOUR, dateadd(hour,-7,GETUTCDATE())))]
FROM
  TABLE AS TAB
```

Comment: No, you cannot do what you want (without using dynamic SQL).  The reason is that you have a bad data model.  You should have one row per hour, not one column per hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dynamic TSQL for the job. You can encapsulate the below script in a scalar function if you want to. I'm assuming the data type for all numbered columns is int.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (OUTVALUE int);
DELETE FROM @tbl;
DECLARE @columnName nvarchar(128) = CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, dateadd(hour,-7,GETUTCDATE())) AS varchar(128));
IF LEN(@columnName) = 1 SET @columnName = '0' + @columnName;
DECLARE @dynamicSql nvarchar(500) = 'SELECT TOP 1 TAB.[' + @columnName + '] FROM TABLE AS TAB;';
INSERT INTO @tbl EXEC sp_executesql @dynamicSql;
SELECT OUTVALUE FROM @tbl;
```

As mentioned by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) this is a really bad table design. The table should really have 2 columns: one to indicate the hour of the day and the other the associated value.

Comment: I know that structure of tables is bad, but i'm not owner of this and I can't change its structure. How much danger is use this method talking about sql inyection? @t4r4z0k

Comment: If you create a scalar function on the server out of this script that takes no arguments and only relies on the current time via built-in function GETUTCDATE() then there's no risk of SQL injection whatsoever. Remember: creation of the dynamic SQL code is on server-side and nothing happens on the client-side in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
(
[01] int,[02] int,[03] int,[04] int,[05] int,
[06] int,[07] int,[08] int,[09] int,[10] int,
[11] int,[12] int,[13] int,[14] int,[15] int,
[16] int,[17] int,[18] int,[19] int,[20] int,
[21] int,[22] int,[23] int,[00] int
);

insert into @t
values(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 10, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 150, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 500);


select DATEPART(HOUR, dateadd(hour,-7,GETUTCDATE())),
choose(1+DATEPART(HOUR, dateadd(hour,-7,GETUTCDATE())), 
[00],[01],[02],[03],[04],[05],[06],[07],[08],[09],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23])
FROM @t AS TAB;

select 
choose(1+DATEPART(HOUR, '20210116 00:00:00'), 
[00],[01],[02],[03],[04],[05],[06],[07],[08],[09],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23])
FROM @t AS TAB;
```